# Filtering with an array of objects Regex in mongodb and mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, mongodb, full-text-search

I'm trying to create a `dynamic` filter that can be implemented using at least 3 letters. I've got a lot of fields which i will be filtering against.

As an example, If I am trying to find users by `email`, I want to be able to type "@gma" or at least "gma" and ideally,  it should return an array of all users containing the specified filtering value. This should be the same when searching for properties like `firstName` and so on

My current solution only works if I provide a full value that matches what I already have in my database. e.g `test@gmail.com` for `email` or `john` for `firstName`. I want to be able to type `jo` for the latter.

```
const regexPattern = new RegExp(["^", filterUsersByValue, "$"].join(""), "i");
const filteredU = UserModel.find({ [filterUsersBy]: regexPattern})
```

Comment: Do you want the key value to be dynamic too? The user gives you the key and value to regex and you create the query?

Comment: Yes i'd like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, since you are using JS you can create the `find` object like this:

```
let findObj = {}
findObj[userKey] = {$regex:userFilter, $options:"i"}
const filteredU = UserModel.find(findObj)
```

This creates que object like this:

```js
const userFilter = "gma"
const userKey = "email"
let findObj = {}
findObj[userKey] = {$regex:userFilter,$options:"i"}
console.log(findObj)
```

What is the same that in [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5gUaPBUEqQ1)

Comment: Thanks mate. this should do